# TYPO3 Extbase - How to call a controller action from external

Tags: php, typo3, extbase

Lets say I have an extension called `my_extension` and in the my_extension a plugin called `apiResponse`.

Then I have in my controller a function called `sendApiDataAction`.

How can I call this `sendApiDataAction` from external via a usual http GET request?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, you need these information from your extension:

- extensionKey (that's easy, in your example it's `myExtension`)
- pluginName (that's the name you defined in your `ext_localconf.php` where you assign the actions)
- actionName (in your example `sendApiData` - without the `action`)
- controllerName (that's the controller where your action is)
- pageId (that's the page id where your plugin is implemented)
- namespace (that's a name built from your plugin and your extension, in your case `tx_myextension_{pluginName}`

Then, you can access the action by

`http(s)://your.domain.tld/index.php?id={pageId}&{namespace}[controller]={controllerName}&{namespace}[action]={actionName}`

Comment: Awesome thanks, but what If there is no pageId since the controller isn't integrated on a page, since it is just an API?

Comment: If you want to use it without pageId, I would suggest to use a page type.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you're using the same extension for calling the external plugin. You can use fluid viewhelper 
to create URL for calling controller action.

1) If you want to use URL for calling action use below [Uri / ActionViewHelper](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/7.5.0/Uri/ActionViewHelper.html).

```
<f:uri.action action="NULL" arguments="{foo: 'bar'}" controller="NULL" extensionName="NULL" pluginName="NULL" pageUid="123" pageType="123" noCache="1" noCacheHash="1" section="''" format="''" linkAccessRestrictedPages="1" additionalParams="{foo: 'bar'}" absolute="1" addQueryString="1" argumentsToBeExcludedFromQueryString="{foo: 'bar'}" addQueryStringMethod="NULL">
</f:uri.action>
```

You can use In-line notation.

```
    {f:uri.action(action: 'NULL', arguments: {foo: 'bar'}, controller: 'NULL', extensionName: 'NULL', pluginName: 'NULL', pageUid: 123, pageType: 123, noCache: 1, noCacheHash: 1, section: '''', format: '''', linkAccessRestrictedPages: 1, additionalParams: {foo: 'bar'}, absolute: 1, addQueryString: 1, argumentsToBeExcludedFromQueryString: {foo: 'bar'}, addQueryStringMethod: 'NULL')}
```

2) [Using Form](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/fluid/7.5.0/FormViewHelper.html): If you're submitting the form, you have a configuration for the form to calling the action.

```
<f:form additionalAttributes="{foo: 'bar'}" data="{foo: 'bar'}" action="NULL" arguments="{foo: 'bar'}" controller="NULL" extensionName="NULL" pluginName="NULL" pageUid="123" object="[mixed]" pageType="123" noCache="1" noCacheHash="1" section="''" format="''" additionalParams="{foo: 'bar'}" absolute="1" addQueryString="1" argumentsToBeExcludedFromQueryString="{foo: 'bar'}" fieldNamePrefix="NULL" actionUri="NULL" objectName="NULL" hiddenFieldClassName="NULL" enctype="NULL" method="NULL" name="NULL" onreset="NULL" onsubmit="NULL" class="NULL" dir="NULL" id="NULL" lang="NULL" style="NULL" title="NULL" accesskey="NULL" tabindex="123" onclick="NULL">
</f:form>
```

Hope this help you!

Comment: Thanks for your help, bit i didnt mean with a fluid ViewHelper. I neey to call that link from another website that didnt use typo3 or fluid.

Comment: Create link with `f:uri.action` and use the URL from external website